# Alternative to SSH on Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, ssh

What software can I use to provide the same features as SSH (openssh-server)? I have a busy server that I am losing all SSH connectivity once in a while. I can't find a solution to yet, we are investigating the possible causes but meanwhile we want to have a safe alternative, so we weren't locked out again (and have to reboot the server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try other SSH servers such as *lsh* or Dropbear, which have less features and are not as thoroughly tested, but can be a good temporary alternative regardless.

There exists a Telnet server *netkit-telnet-ssl* which supports SSL/TLS encryption and authentication. However, even though TLS can provides sufficient security (provided the sysadmin is not lazy and obtains a SSL certificate), Telnet remains a generally poorly designed protocol for daily use.

The Telnet and *rlogin* servers from Heimdal and MIT *krb5-appl* Kerberos suites have support for Kerberos authentication and encryption; however, the crypto code in MIT *telnetd* is limited to DES64, and *rlogin* is from my experience even more of a pain in the ass to set up than Telnet.

Finally, **check the system log**, optionally after increasing LogLevel in `sshd_config`. You might just find the cause of SSH loss.

Comment: Can I also install openssh from source and run on another port? Or it will conflict with the other, too?

Comment: @JhonnyEverson: It *might* conflict, but if it uses autoconf then `./configure --prefix=/opt/openssh` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [sshd](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8) of Openssh has a `-f config_file` and a `-p port` option I surmise that you can run two of them concurrently on different ports (using distinct config files if necessary) - one could be used only in the event of problems with the first and could be more tightly restricted.

You'd have to set up the startup scripts appropriately (rc.local?) or run one out of (x)inetd?